# Windows: How to change the system/dialog font?

Tags: windows, fonts

I switched over to Cleartype on Windows XP about 3 years ago. And in the Theme settings I used Vista (made-for-Cleartype) fonts for all the UI widgets.

However, certain system dialogs of Windows and Windows utilities still show up in the older Windows font. That now looks butt-ugly under Cleartype. Anyone knows how to change this system font too?

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of this and put it in the question?

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly would you like changed ?

Answer (score 2):

**Sometimes the font is hard-coded into the application.**

In that case you have no chance to change their font through the global Windows settings.

Remember when Microsoft decided to lighten the dialog background color a little bit? (Windows 2000/ME) Suddenly many applications had dialogs with a mixture of dark and light gray colors. (Most times when glyphs/icons were not transparent and instead had the old dialog color background)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, indeed, with the fonts used for [MS Shell Dlg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374112(v=vs.85).aspx) which, by default, is [Microsoft Sans Serif](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=244). The latter is described as "metrically compatible with the MS Sans bitmap font" which hints at why high-dpi scaling can get messed up.

Solution: right-click over the Start button (windows icon) and select "Run", the type "regedit" and press Enter to open the Registry. Then locate

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes
```

in the registry and change `MS Shell Dlg` to something else - `Arial` or `Tahoma` will work, but to look like the rest of Windows I chose `Segoe UI`.

You can now back to normal Dialog or...